# Jumping to tags instead of lines in a text-file opened by vim

Tags: tags

I'm using vim as note-taking software.   My notes grow to thousands of lines across 7 different files.

If I was writing code, I would be able to jump to a function definition in a different file with a vim plugin.   Or if I open a list of compile errors or grep matches in vim, I could jump to a line in a different file with just two keystrokes.

My problem is that I want to jump to one note file from another.   This will probably involve tagging the location i wish to jump to.

Hopefully you know what I'm asking now.  I can't type in a reference to a second file, (other than using the exact line number file:999 ), but I still need a way to type in references in the files, since I want to organize the same tasks across different note-files.

How can I do this?  Would writing in markdown help?

[How can I configure custom vim tags for my text file notes?](https://superuser.com/questions/290082/how-can-i-configure-custom-vim-tags-for-my-text-file-notes) offers a solution by binding a key to vimgrep.

Comment: also this user suggests running a php script: https://superuser.com/a/1330906/88618